# Loop through a Filtered PivotTable, adding each visible value to the next cell in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently at a bit of a standstill with looping through a Filtered PivotTable, and adding each visible value to the next cell in a pre-determined range.

So far I have put together the following, amateurish, vba code. But my output is not as desired. It seems to be adding only the very final value to all the cells in the provided range.

**See Edits, Code is extracting all data from PivotTable, ignoring the Filter in place and not stopping once reaching end of Union(A,B,C,D)**

```
Private Sub GenerateConsumableCard_Click()

Dim Pt As PivotTable
Dim Pf As PivotField
Dim Pi As PivotItem
Dim C As Range

Set Pt = Sheets("Cards").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields("Consumable Name")
Set KB1 = Sheets("Cards").Range("D11")
Set KB2 = Sheets("Cards").Range("K11")
Set KB3 = Sheets("Cards").Range("D22")
Set KB4 = Sheets("Cards").Range("K22")
Set CRange = Union(KB1, KB2, KB3, KB4)

With Pt
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone

For Each C In CRange.Cells
    For Each Pi In Pf.PivotItems
        If Pi.Visible = True Then
           C.Value = Pi
        End If
    Next Pi
Next C

End With
End Sub
```

The idea behind what I've put together being that; each cell in the range will have a different value based on the information currently present in the PivotTable.
I.E. The first visible value in the PivotTable will go to Cell D11, the Second to Cell K11, the third to cell D22.... etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

It seems I have more than one problem. I believe I may be referencing the complete wrong part of my PivotTable? Below is an image of the table as it currently stands.

As before, I'm wanting to pull the individual values under "Consumable Name" and put them in order into the cell values within "CRange".

[ExamplePivotTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KLIr.png)

**Edit2:**

So I've made a few more changes, but none of which are working.

```
Private Sub GenerateConsumableCard_Click()

Dim Pt As PivotTable
Dim Pf As PivotField
Dim Pi As PivotItem
Dim C As Range

Set Pt = Sheets("KanBans").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Pf = Pt.PivotFields("Consumable Name")
Set KB1 = Sheets("KanBans").Range("D11")
Set KB2 = Sheets("KanBans").Range("K11")
Set KB3 = Sheets("KanBans").Range("D22")
Set KB4 = Sheets("KanBans").Range("K22")
Set CRange = Union(KB1, KB2, KB3, KB4)

With Pt
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone

For Each Pi In Pf.VisibleItems
For Each C In CRange.Cells
           C.Value = Pi
     Next
Next

End With
End Sub
```

It now seems to be correctly looping through the PivotTable, but is ignoring the filter placed on the data and extracting all items until the last item.
I believe I may have also confused myself with:

```
For Each C In CRange
```

as it correctly iterates through the ranges, but does not stop once all ranges have been filled.

Warm Regards

Answer (score 0):

The code in the example runs on all the items in the pivot, and each item goes into all the CRange cells leaving the last item in all the cells.

Since it is always 4 items in the pivot, and 4 items in CRange, we can iterate through any of them, but not both, so you don't need nested loops.

And then `VisibleItems` is not what you are looking for, you should use the items of `DataRange`.

```
 i = 1
 For Each C In CRange.Cells
       C.Value = Pf.DataRange.Item(i)
       i = i + 1
 Next
```